# Prints matrix with different random numbers in each column

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanna learn how to make my code more Pythonic, I'm still a newb.
Advises on classes and functions I could've used are welcomed.

```py
import random as r

n = 7   #This number defines the size of the square matrix

def print_mat(mat):
    """ This function will be used to display the matrix
    """
    for row in range(len(mat)):
        for line in range(len(mat[0])):
            print(mat[row][line],end="\t")
        print("\n")


def is_used(test_num):
    """ This function tests if the argument has already been used
    in the column of the matrix thanks to the array already_used
    """
    for used_num in already_used:
        if test_num == used_num:
            return True
    return False


A = [[0]*n for _ in range(n)] #Creates matrix of size n*n

for row in range(n):
    """ Will loop n times for each column of the matrix
    The array bellow will allow to sort out already used random numbers
    """
    already_used = [0 for _ in range(n)]

    for line in range(n):
        """ Will loop n times for each line of the matrix
        """
        rand_num = r.randint(1,n)   #Generate random number between [1;n]

        while is_used(rand_num) == True:
            rand_num = r.randint(1,n)
            """ Will loop until rand_num is a num that hasn't been used
            """
        A[line][row] = rand_num #Assignes the available rand_num to the matrix
        already_used[line] = rand_num
        
print("\nMatrice A = ")
print_mat(A)    #Prints the matrix using the function defined above
```

One previous output :

```py
Matrice A =
6       4       7       4       6       5       6

3       1       6       5       1       4       2

4       3       2       3       2       1       4

2       2       1       7       3       6       5

1       5       4       2       4       7       1

5       6       5       1       5       2       3

7       7       3       6       7       3       7
```

Thanks a lot <3

Comment: Hopefully someone points to the [Fisher–Yates Shuffle](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/). (Read the link, very helpful.)

Comment: You were that person, and I'm reading through it rn ;)
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, your objective is to create and print a square matrix, where each column must have unique values.

If that is the case, and considering you are already using `random` module, it is better to use `random.shuffle` or `random.sample`. Now `random.shuffle` modifies a `list` in place, so that can create reference issues, and to avoid that we will need to create a copy anyways, so `random.sample` would be more suitable in this case.

If you use `random.sample` there is no need to check whether a value has already been used while filling a cell, we can assign one row at a time. Furthermore, there is no need to build an empty matrix at all, we can directly create a matrix with random columns using `zip`. So first approach could be something like this:

```
import random

def generate_col(allowed_nums, length):
    """
    This function will generate col of provided `length`
    with random ordering out of `allowed_nums`.
    """
    return random.sample(allowed_nums, length)

def print_matrix(mat):
    """ 
    This function will be used to display the matrix
    """
    for row in mat:
        print(*row, sep='\t', end=2*'\n')

def build_matrix(n):
    """
    Creates a square matrix of size n.
    """
    allowed_nums = range(1, n+1)
    all_cols = [generate_col(allowed_nums, n) for _ in range(n)]
    return list(zip(*all_cols))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 7   #This number defines the size of the square matrix
    
    A = build_matrix(n)

    print("\nMatrice A = ")
    print_matrix(A)    #Prints the matrix using the function defined above
```

If you plan to work with multiple matrices, you can consider making a `class`. That would hide implementation details, and make the usage much cleaner:

```
import random

class RandomSquareMatrix:
    '''
    nxn Square Matrix filled with unique random numbers
    in range (1, n] in each column.
    '''
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.allowed_vals = range(1, n+1)
        self.matrix = self.build_matrix()

    def build_matrix(self):
        """
        This function will generate col of provided `length`
        with random ordering out of `allowed_nums`.
        """
        all_cols = [self.generate_col() for _ in range(self.n)]
        return list(zip(*all_cols))

    def generate_col(self):
        return random.sample(self.allowed_vals, self.n)

    def __str__(self):
        """ 
        This function will be used to display the matrix
        when it is printed
        """
        row_sep = 2 * '\n'
        col_sep = '\t'
        return row_sep.join(
            [col_sep.join(map(str, row)) 
            for row in self.matrix]
        )

    def __repr__(self):
        """
        This function will be used to display the matrix information.
        Example:
         >>> RandomSquareMatrix(3)
         <RandomSquareMatrix: 3x3>
        """
        cls_name = type(self).__name__

if __name__ == '__main__':
    B = RandomSquareMatrix(7)
    print('Matrice B =')
    print(B)
```

**NOTE:** I think, in this case, it is better to `import random` and use `random.sample`, instead of `from random import sample`. Because you are using it only in one place, shouldn't be that hard to write it once, also `random.sample` is more clear in my view.
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. I didn't know that the function shuffle existed!
I also love the way you printed the matrix in 1 line^^

Comment: (and many other things in your version of the code) <3
I'll take my time to assimilate that :)

Comment: Very concise and well structured code. I also really like how elegantly you transposed the matrix with `list(zip(*all_cols))`. Very nice! Upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

The `random.shuffle` method could be very useful here to get a random ordering of the integers from 1 to n without having to track what you've already used, and therefore make your code a lot more concise.

It works like this:

```
from random import shuffle
my_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']
shuffle(my_list)
print(my_list)
```

Example output: `['B', 'A', 'C']`

========================================

Using it, your code might look something like:

```
from random import shuffle
n=7

def print_mat(mat):
    """ This function will be used to display the matrix
    """
    for row in range(len(mat)):
        for line in range(len(mat[0])):
            print(mat[row][line],end="\t")
        print("\n")

A = [[0]*n for _ in range(n)] #Creates matrix of size n*n

# List of integers from 1 to n
one_to_n = list(range(1,n+1))

for column in range(n):
    # Shuffle the list
    shuffle(one_to_n)
    # Use the shuffled list to populate the column
    for row in range(n):
        A[row][column] = one_to_n[row]

print_mat(A)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. I didn't know that the function shuffle existed!

Comment: Glad it helped! Please vote useful on the answer if you have a moment.